# WooCommerce - How to create a package deal based on cart contents

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So I am trying to create a package deal based on the cart contents.

What I need:
To scan the cart to check if there are 4 items, from the same category, with the same variation attribute. If so, discount the price of each item to a set amount each (essentially creating a bundle price).

This discount can only be applied in sets of 4. Eg. If there are 5 items of the same, only 4 will be discounted.

There are 3 categories which this will apply to. Eg. Cat 1, discount items to $5. Cat 2, discount items to $10. Cat 3, discount to $15.

I then need to calculate all the regular (or sale) prices before the new set price, and calculate the difference.

I would then like to display a "You've saved $x.xx amount" message in the mini-cart, and potentially in other locations on checkout etc.

What I have so far:

```
function action_woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;
    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    /* SETTINGS */

    // Specific categories
    $specific_categories = 'craft';

    // Min quantity
    $minimun_quantity = 4;

    /* END SETTINGS */
    
    // Counter
    $current_quantity = 0;

    $flag_mix = false;

    // Loop though each cart item
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        // Get product id
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        $the_weight = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_weight' );
        $regular_price      = $product->get_regular_price();
        $sale_price         = $product->get_sale_price();


        // Has certain category     
        if ( has_term( $specific_categories, 'product_cat', $product_id ) && $the_weight == '7' ) {
            // Quantity
            $product_quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];

            // Add to total
            $current_quantity += $product_quantity;

            if ( $current_quantity >= $minimun_quantity ) {

                $flag_mix = true;

                // Store data (discounted product)
                $cart_item_data = $cart_item['data'];   

            }
        }
    }

    if ( $flag_mix ) {
        $cart_item_data->set_price( 9.99 );

        // define the woocommerce_after_mini_cart callback 
        function action_woocommerce_after_mini_cart(  ) { 
            var_dump($the_weight);
            echo '<div class="card bg-light">
              <div class="card-body" style="line-height:20px;">
                <span class="fw-600">Congratulations!</span>
                <p class="card-text">You\'ve built a craft beer box!</p>
              </div>
            </div>';
        }; 
                 
        // add the action 
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_mini_cart', 'action_woocommerce_after_mini_cart', 10, 0 ); 
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'action_woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 10, 1 );
```

So where I am at is:

I am able pull in the data I need, and it seems to be working correctly (with just one category at the moment), for the most part.

It is scanning the cart items, correctly validating that there are 4 items, from the Craft category, that each share the same attribute with the value of "7".

The message then appears correctly beneath the mini-cart once there are 4 correct items in the cart, however currently only the last item in the mini-cart is showing the new set price.

I am also unsure of how to go about calculating the difference between the original prices, comparing that to the total of the items with savings, and displaying how much the customer has saved.

Looking for any help or advice I can get (I know my code is sloppy, still learning)

Comment: You are updating the product price outside foreach loop may be that's the reason it's updating last product price. put this line of code inside foreach loop $cart_item_data->set_price( 9.99 );

Comment: @ShaikhAejazAhmed just tried that, unfortunately - same result.

Comment: Please try this filter to set the price with the loop 'woocommerce_cart_item_price'

Comment: @ShaikhAejazAhmed no, still the same result.